# Flask repeat URL parameters in template links

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Python/Flask for a simple database application.  I have a query that shows transactions filtered by various parameters.  I pass in these parameters as URL parameters to my "view_transactions" Flask view function.

The query is paginated to show a few transactions at a time.  I need to repeat all the original query URL parameters on the pagination ">>" and "<<" links, as at the moment they are lost, meaning the filter is cleared when navigating the results.

I could do this by passing all the parameters explicitly by name into the url_for I'm using to build the ">>"/"<<" links, thus:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('view_transactions', page=transactions.next_num, account=account_parm, category=category_parm, ...) }}">{{ _('>>') }}</a>
```

The views.py code I'm using is:

```
@app.route('/view/transactions', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/view/transactions/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def view_transactions(page=1):

    tq = db.session.query(Transaction).order_by(desc(Transaction.id))

    get_temp = request.args.get('category')
    if get_temp != None:
        tq = tq.filter_by(category=get_temp)
    get_temp = request.args.get('account')
    if get_temp != None:
        tq = tq.filter_by(account=get_temp)
    start_date = request.args.get('start_date')
    end_date = request.args.get('end_date')
    if  start_date != None:
        tq = tq.filter(Transaction.date>=(start_date))
    if  end_date != None:
        tq = tq.filter(Transaction.date<=(end_date))

    transactions = paginate(tq, page, POSTS_PER_PAGE)

    return render_template('transactions.html',
                           title='Transactions',
                           transactions=transactions,
                           account_parm=request.args.get('account'),
                           category_parm=request.args.get('category'))
```

And the URL I'm using to access the page is
http://localhost:5000/view/transactions/1?account=AT1&category=CT2

However, this is tedious and a pain to maintain as I introduce extra parameters.  Is there a way of automatically passing all the same URL parameters used on the parent page on the links on that page?

Comment: Oliver - please provide the exact code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Now edited to include the view code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `request.query_string`, as `request` is available to the templates as part of the [standard context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context):

```
<a href="{{ url_for('view_transactions',
                    page=transactions.next_num,
                    account=account_parm,
                    category=category_parm,
           ...) }}?{{request.query_string}}">{{ _('>>') }}</a>
```

Comment: An empty `{{request.query_string}}` evaluates to `b''` on my system. `?a` is printed as `b'a'`.

Comment: The correct and working call is: `{{request.query_string.decode()}}`

Comment: @Robert - it works like that for you because you are using Python 3

Comment: According to my knowledge "Python 2.x is legacy, Python 3.x is the present and future of the language". Therefore please answer for Python 3  unless the question is an explicit Python 2 question. Or at least mention that the solution is for Python 2 only.

Comment: If you look at the date of the question, is was asked last year and notice it was checked as accepted by the OP which means it worked for them. You should have asked a new question, referring back to this one and asking why it doesn't work - where the correct answer would have been _"For Python 3, you have to decode the bytestring returned with `.decode()`"_.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can always generate the URL generation **`HELPER`**. Please visit - http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/

Here is the probable helper function through which you can pass the extra parameters -

```
def url_for_other_page(page):
    args = request.view_args.copy()
    args['page'] = page
    return url_for(request.endpoint, **args)
app.jinja_env.globals['url_for_other_page'] = url_for_other_page
```

In the code above you can always extend `args` further with extra parameters such as

- args['extra-params1'] = extra-params-1
- args['extra-params2'] = extra-params-2
- args['extra-params3'] = extra-params-3
- These parameters can further be used in jinja2 template - {{ url_for_other_page(extra-param2) }}">{{ extra-param2 }} for any url.

**Jinja2 template**

```
{% macro render_pagination(pagination) %}
  <div class=pagination>
  {%- for page in pagination.iter_pages() %}
    {% if page %}
      {% if page != pagination.page %}
        <a href="{{ url_for_other_page(page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <strong>{{ page }}</strong>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <span class=ellipsis>…</span>
    {% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  {% if pagination.has_next %}
    <a href="{{ url_for_other_page(pagination.page + 1)
      }}">Next &raquo;</a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

**Please make sure you refer the URL http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/ for exact explanation.**

Comment: Thanks... I've tried this and it hasn't worked... request.view_args just contains {'page': 1}, which is the parameter to the view function.  It doesn't contain the parameters after the URL ? (i.e. account and category).  Any ideas?